# When will this variable be assigned?

Tags: vhdl

Here is the code:

```
process(SRSTN, CSN, WRN,AB) is
begin  
    if SRSTN = '0' then
        WR0 <= (OTHERS => '0');
    elsif CSN = '0' then
        if WRN = '0' then
            case AB(15 downto 0) is
                when "0101000100010000" =>
                    WR0(15 downto 0) <= DB(15 downto 0);
                when OTHERS   =>    NULL;
                     WR0(15 downto 8) <= "00000000" ;
                end case;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

I'm wondering when will
`WR0(15 downto 8) <= "00000000"`be executed. Is it assigned everytime except AB equals 0101000100010000?

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 10.9 Case statement, para 9 (in part) "The choice **others** is only allowed for the last alternative and as its only choice; it stands for all values (possibly none) not given in the choices of previous alternatives." para 5 (in part) "For an ordinary case statement,..., if the expression is the name of an object whose subtype is locally static, whether a scalar type or an array type, then each value of the subtype shall be represented once and only  once  in  the  set  of  choices  of  the  case  statement,  and  no  other  value  is  allowed;... " Choices are exclusive.

Comment: Perhaps you could ask about a specific problem instead of a theoretical endeavor? See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question without a [mcve] leaves no ability to provide a demonstrable answer to future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `signal` or `variable` (inside the process). A possible solution could be:

```vhdl
architecture Beh of Test is
    signal temp : std_logic_vector((WR0'LENGTH - 1) downto 0) := (others => '0');
 begin
 
    WR0 <= std_logic_vector(temp);
 
    process(SRSTN, CSN, WRN,AB) is
    begin  
        if SRSTN = '0' then
            temp <= (OTHERS => '0');
        elsif CSN = '0' then
            if WRN = '0' then
                case AB(15 downto 0) is
                    when "0101000100010000" =>
                        temp(15 downto 0) <= DB(15 downto 0);
                    when OTHERS   =>
                        temp(15 downto 8) <= "00000000" ;
                    end case;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end Beh;
```

> The `WR0` output will be imediatly assigned if one of the `inputs` `SRSTN`, `CSN`, `WRN`, `AB` is changing.